# Device Orientation not getting.

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Currently i am working on IOS 7 and my problem is i am not able to get orientation of current device in ViewDidLoad method.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
        NSLog(@"i am in landscape mode");
    }
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
        NSLog(@"i am in portrait mode");
    }
}
```

I write this code in my `FirstViewController.m`,and when i run my application no condition become true out of them,
can anybody help me why no condition become true even i run my application in portrait mode.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited the code please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    //Landscape mode
}
else
{
    //Portrait mode
}
```

**EDIT** : Use `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape` and `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait` method to find `orientation mode`

Comment: :: Its working fine...but still there is one problem.it gives portrait orientation default that is fine but when i change portrait to landscape it will returns me portrait. and when i again change landscape to portrait it will returns me landscape.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 UIInterfaceOrientation  orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
  if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
  {
      NSLog(@"i am in landscape mode");
  }
 if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
     NSLog(@"i am in portrait mode");
 }
```

oky u hav other orientation call back methods this one called before rotation is going to occur `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` and this one just after second one `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation`, for example

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
   UIInterfaceOrientation  orientation = toInterfaceOrientation; //hear toInterfaceOrientation contains the which orientation is device is turning to 
   if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
   {
       NSLog(@"i am in landscape mode");
   }
   if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
       NSLog(@"i am in portrait mode");
  }
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
   UIInterfaceOrientation  orientation = fromInterfaceOrientation; // hear fromInterfaceOrientation contains previous state of the orientation 
   if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
   {
      NSLog(@"i am in landscape mode");
   }
   if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
      NSLog(@"i am in portrait mode");
   }
}
```

for more information see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)

hope this helps u .. :)

Comment: Its working fine...but still there is one problem.it gives portrait orientation default that is fine but when i change portrait to landscape it will returns me portrait. and when i again change landscape to portrait it will returns me landscape.\