# Landscape detected while in Portrait mode (Simulator)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I have an app started in the IOS Simulator and my app thinks the device is in Landscape mode while the device is in portrait mode.

Any hints, why this happen and how to detect the portrait correctly ?

[image]

Code:

```
    let raworientation=UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue;

    if raworientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue {
        return "PortraitUpsideDown";
    }else if raworientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue {
        return "Portrait";
    }else if raworientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue {
        return "LandscapeLeft"; // IT GOES HERE !!!!, while the device is in portrait !!!!
    }else if raworientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue {
        return "LandscapeRight";
    }else{
        return "unknown";
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Another thing which seems to be wrong too.
In case of Portrait upside down, the width and height measures are wrong too:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;
print("W:" + String(screenSize.width) + "H:" + String(screenSize.height));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Device Orientation not getting.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661792/device-orientation-not-getting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
let raworientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
```

to get the orientation of the UI

I tested this code in the simulator and both ways work for all orientations

```
    let raworientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation;

    if raworientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown {
        println("PortraitUpsideDown");
    }else if raworientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait {
        println("Portrait");
    }else if raworientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft {
        println("LandscapeLeft"); 
    }else if raworientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight {
        println("LandscapeRight");
    }else{
        println("unknown");
    }
```

other method

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        case (.PortraitUpsideDown): println("PortraitUpsideDown");
        case (.Portrait): println("Portrait");
        case (.LandscapeLeft): println("LandscapeLeft");
        case (.LandscapeRight): println("LandscapeRight");
        default: println("unknown");
    }

}
```

Edit:
There seems to be a bug when you just click the checkbox in Xcode to enable upside down orientation, so you have to add code to do it in your view controller.

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried the first one, which is working partly. When the simulator is in portrait upsidedown position, the code goes into "Portrait", which is much better then "Landscape" (My Issue). I guess it is because also the content is upside down. How can I achieve that the content is turned also in upsidedown position ?